# If an insertion in parentheses ends with a smiley, how do I distinguish between the two?

Tags: punctuation, writing, parentheses, emoticons

I know smileys are not part of written language (yet), and any questions about them are irrelevant to linguistics and are kind of not serious. So take my question with a smiley then.

It bugs me every time I'm facing this situation: if an insertion in parentheses ends with a smiley, what should I do?

> - A lot of insertions in parentheses (well, if it's not Lisp :) ) can be annoying.
> - A lot of insertions in parentheses (well, if it's not Lisp :)) can be annoying.
> - A lot of insertions in parentheses (well, if it's not Lisp :) can be annoying.

I don't like any of the above. Any (clever) suggestions?

Comment: I prefer to use a different smiley in parentheses (like this :P), or use a Japanese-style smiley ^_^.

Comment: :)) looks like an emoticon with a double-chin.

Comment: @dbkk, if you'd post that as an answer, I'd vote it up. :)

Comment: (This is how I like it :])

Comment: Just as an aside, where is this used outside of chat rooms and informal e-mails?  I haven't seen emoticons in "serious" writing except as inset e-mails.  I certainly wouldn't expect to see them get past the editors at the *New York Times*.  They don't even acknowledge that people can tweet things.

Comment: See comments on [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11155/is-it-acceptable-to-nest-parentheses) - (did these inspire your question?)

Comment: The backward-smiley-closing-bracket (:)

Comment: This is one of several reasons that I'm more likely to use the XMLish <grin> notation than an emoticon.

Comment: This is one reason why i use the :/ emoticon everywhere. Another is that it fits every situation

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I couldn't resist but post this!

[image: The IAU ban came after the 'redefinition of 'planet' to include the IAU president's mom' incident.]

But seriously, I generally avoid ending a bracketed expression with an emoticon. One solution could however be to use square brackets:

> A lot of insertions in parentheses [well, if it's not Lisp :)] can be annoying.

Though it's rather non-standard, it at least *looks* better. I'm sure almost any reader would understand it too.

Comment: OK, the question is answered :)

Comment: Heh, yeah! XKCD has an answer to anything. But really, it's a bit of a moot point. Personally i just avoid ending a bracketed expression with an emoticon!

Comment: Square brackets look a lot better indeed. People with math/CS background though usually take square brackets as an "optional" insertion, but I think it's still fine.

Comment: I solve the "mismatched parenthesis" problem by using [Japanese smileys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticon#Asian_style). \\(^_^)/ Likewise, I don't tilt my head 90° before smiling in real life.

Comment: "A lot of insertions in parentheses (well, if it's not Lisp \\(^_^)/) can be annoying." Hey not bad!

Comment: Today's one is pretty good too: http://xkcd.com/859/

Comment: Also consider, "A lot of insertions in parentheses (well, if it's not Lisp :] )can be annoying."

Answer (score 30):

It’s the twenty-first century!  We have a much better alternative to old ASCII emoticons: Unicode!

> A lot of insertions in parentheses (well, if it's not Lisp ☺) can be annoying.

… well, ok, I admit that I do not always like this, either. ☹

Comment: Come on, Unicode can do a lot more impressive [٩(•̮̮̃•̃)۶](http://superuser.com/q/52671/35237)

Comment: ...although with something like the [EmojiOne color font](https://github.com/eosrei/EmojiOne-Color-Font) it actually looks bearable

Answer (score 23):

I tend to leave a space on both sides, like this

> A lot of insertions in parentheses ( well, if it's not Lisp :) ) can be annoying.

also, using dashes is worth trying

> A lot of insertions in parentheses — well, if it's not Lisp :) — can be annoying.

Comment: After the recent work on PL/SQL, at first glance: He has left a comment at the end of the line :-)

Comment: I usually go for the square brackets myself, but a proper dash seems to work just as well. :)

Comment: The emoticon is drooling. :)

Answer (score 13):

There really isn't any way to make it not look weird (as [famously documented by xkcd](http://xkcd.com/541/)), but my preferred form, and I believe the more common practice, is to "merge" the smiley with the closing parenthesis.  (So, like this. :)

Answer (score 11):

I think James Joyce would go for a dash instead...

> A lot of insertions in parentheses -
>   well, if it's not Lisp :) - can be
>   annoying.

Answer (score 8):

In direct conflict with chaos, my preferred form, and I believe the more common practice, is to separate the smiley from the closing parenthesis by a single space.  :-)

Normally a space should not be included between a parenthesis and the word it is adjacent to, but when using a parenthesis as part of a separate lexical element, spacing between the "word-element" parenthesis and the "syntax-element" parenthesis is very helpful to avoid confusion.  Otherwise you might be sending a double-chin smiley and still have no closing parenthesis.

The best solution, of course, is to avoid such a potentially confusing issue in the first place:  grow a goatee, so that all your smileys can be of the form ":-)>".

Answer (score 5):

Maybe these ones:

:-P)

:-{)

:-()

:-)-:

Comment: Nice kissing smileys/frownies

Comment: you forgot C:, :D, and ^.^ among others....:)

Answer (score 5):

Use [٩(•̮̮̃•̃)۶ Unicode smileys](https://superuser.com/q/52671/35237)

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there is not a defined standard as yet, however I find that putting a space between the smiley and the close parentheses makes it look less like a double parentheses mistake (though it can look jarring at the same time :) )

I would certainly, as a pedant, NOT drop the last parentheses (especially where I am not at the end of a sentence :) as it is ambiguous as to whether the parenthesed clause has completed yet, although I would readily admit a mid bracket smiley is particularly jarring and ugly).

Answer (score 2):

There should not be any spaces after the smiley, in the same way there is no space between a word and a closing parenthesis.

In some messages sent through IM applications, a space is added after the smiley and before a parenthesis, as in some of these applications the textual smilies are replaced from a icon/image; in these applications, the double parentheses are used for a different smiley.
This could explain why some people are used to add a space after a smiley, and before the following parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

(what about this (: )

ok... not good enough...

Answer (score 2):

I usually insert the extra space in between the smile and the closing parenthesis for a couple of reasons:

- The extra space prevents unintended tokenizing of the second parenthesis.  It bugs me when I write `choose (A) or (B)` and the text parser converts the capital B and the right parenthesis to a "cool shades emoticon".
- It looks clearer to me.  Without the extra space it just looks like my keyboard hiccuped on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a square bottomed smiley with a space after it.

> A lot of insertions in parentheses (well, if it's not Lisp :] ) can be annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way, how would you do a frowny face?

- A lot of insertions in parentheses (well, if it's not Lisp :( ) can be annoying.
- A lot of insertions in parentheses (well, if it's not Lisp :() can be annoying.
- A lot of insertions in parentheses (well, if it's not Lisp :( can be annoying.

I suggest none of them. Instead you could put the smiley/frowny outside the parenthesis:

- A lot of insertions in parentheses (well, if it's not Lisp) :( can be annoying.
- A lot of insertions in parentheses (well, if it's not Lisp) :) can be annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Unicode there's different widths of spaces, some of which may be more aesthetically pleasing depending on your preferences.

### Figure Space

> A lot of insertions in parentheses (well, if it's not Lisp :) ) can be annoying.

### Thin Space

> A lot of insertions in parentheses (well, if it's not Lisp :) ) can be annoying.

### Hair Space

> A lot of insertions in parentheses (well, if it's not Lisp :) ) can be annoying.

(Note: some render at different widths depending on font, so experiment with fonts if none of these are satisfactory)