# Thrice or triple?

Tags: meaning, numbers, triple-thrice, recurring-events

There is a fairly well known recipe for *Triple Cooked Chips*. It involves cooking  chips three different ways / times.

Is *triple* cooked correct or should it be called *Thrice Cooked Chips* as they have been cooked three times?

Comment: See *[How common is “thrice”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5580)* and *[Why has the word “thrice” fallen out of common usage?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146043)*.

Comment: You can have *double-stuffed potatoes* and *twice-baked potatoes*. From there, it follows that you would have *triple-stuffed potatoes* but *thrice-baked potatoes*.  I see no reason for chips to be exempt.

Comment: ["Double Baked Pie"](http://i.imgur.com/oeCG1T2.jpg) for reference. Whether it is double-baked remains unknown :p

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pretend it would concern the number two instead of three:

Use thrice when you would use twice.
Use triple when you would use double.

As they have been cooked three times, I would suggest "thrice".
For comparison: I have seen you triple today. Doesn't work, does it?

Comment: *Thrice* isn't exactly part of the everyday language of most English speakers. That's why this link http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/thrice?q=thrice says "old use or Indian English".

Comment: It's true that "I have seen you triple today" doesn't work, but there are some subtleties. Consider *Seinfeld*'s "Did you just double-dip that chip?" \[[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfprRZQxWps)]

Comment: But it doesn't concern the number two instead of three...

Answer (score 8):

If it is a fairly well-known recipe, then the name is a [fixed phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_phrase) by now — and also, well, a *name*. So it cannot be wrong by definition. It's a label, and as far as the English language is concerned, it can be anything at all. You might as well wonder if New York should be called Second York instead. Or Little Pear. It *should* nothing. It just *is*.

Comment: Even if it is a fixed phrase, it doesn't mean that the original grammar was correct. (Maybe I should have mentioned in my question that I was wondering which term is grammatically correct.) Even though triple may sound better, to me, it's grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @DanielGee Both terms are clearly *grammatically* correct. The question is one of semantics, not syntax.

Comment: @DanielGee I got that alright, and my answer stands. *Right now* it is perfectly grammatical, and had it been grammatically incorrect *originally*, which it was not, that would have no bearing whatsoever on what it should be now. But that's beside the point because combining *triple* with a past participle is perfectly grammatical, and has always been.

Comment: +1 for Second York. Although, maybe just renaming it Gotham would do.

Comment: FWIW, I've never heard of 'triple cooked' chips, and if I had before reading this, I would find myself wondering whether the cooking time or temperature were tripled. Then again, I still cringe when I think about a former colleague who wrote about her 'install download' not working. When a few weeks later, I said to her 'congratulate on your promote', she looked at me cluelessly.

Answer (score 5):

Thrice is rather old fashioned these days, even archaic. It's valid, but 'triple' conveys the meaning perfectly adequately.

Comment: I agree that triple sounds better and conveys what the chef is trying to say. However, I've always understood that triple is three of something, thrice is something done three times.

Comment: Language evolves.

Comment: You're right, ElendilTheTall. It is old fashioned and not exactly part of the everyday language of most English speakers.

Comment: @DanielGee One could argue that "triple-cooked" could mean "cooked three times as much" whereas "thrice-cooked" means "cooked three times". But it's pretty obvious from context that a chip that was cooked three times as much as normal would be badly burnt and anyone who says "triple-cooked" probably doesn't mean that.

Comment: "Triple cooked chips" may be read as "cooked triple chips", which has a totally different meaning, but "Triple-cooked chips" isn't so ambiguous. Words connected with a hyphen are interpreted as indivisible, so don't forget to use it if you want to avoid confusion.

Comment: 'I agree that triple sounds better and conveys what the chef is trying to say' - and that's why we use _triple_...

Answer (score 2):

As other people point out, many people consider triple to be a modern 'replacement' for thrice, and in advertising, what matters is your customer's opinions, not grammar nerds on the internet.

That said, thrice is more specific and accurate in this case.

"I had coffee twice/thrice" involves a lot more washing up than having a double coffee or a triple coffee.

So triple cooked chips could simply be cooked for triple the amount of time, at triple the 'normal' temperature, or they could be cooked three separate times.

Thrice cooked chips, however, have to be cooked three separate times. It cannot be one longer/hotter cook.

Using Thrice is more descriptive, and in order to be completely understood, you should use thrice. If you want to sell chips, do some market surveys of your target audience and go with the majority.

Answer (score -2):

"Thrice cooked" is a bit archaic.  Correct English would be "Triply cooked" in my opinion.  "Triple cooked cookies" rather sounds like triple cookies rather than triply cooked.

Comment: *Thrice* is more common than *triply*, and is therefore a better choice.