# Is it acceptable to nest parentheses?

Tags: punctuation, parentheses

Is it acceptable to nest parentheses (for example, if I (meaning myself) write like this)?

Comment: I like to change style of brackets when I nest (on the odd occasion)... in the mathematical style (like this [or this])!

Comment: Related, is it acceptable to integrate a smiley into the last bracket (like this :)?

Comment: @Noldorin - I'm with you on that one.

Comment: @Benjol - I'd say not - either you have a smiley or a closing parenthesis - surely it can't be both (at the same time)? I'd certainly avoid it...

Comment: @CJM: it is common across the web to use the closing parenthesis as the smile - examples elude me right now, as :) is hard to search for!

Comment: @Benjol See xkcd.com/541/.  ;)

Comment: @Maxpm, there's a chance my question was subconsciously inspired by that. (I think programmers have a problem between the illogicality of having unmatched parentheses, and the illogicality of using the closing parenthesis 'twice' :)[)]

Comment: @Benjol: If you know the receiver has graphic representation that shows the smiley as a small image rather than the `:)` it's OK, otherwise, no, it's not ok.

Comment: @awe, don't you mean the opposite? If I'm on Skype, for example. I have to add the extra `)`

Comment: @Benjol: Sorry, I misunderstould your question. My opinion is really that you should not add smiley at all inside a parenthesis - integrated or not (unless its shown graphical like I said). Again, see [xkcd.com/541](http://xkcd.com/541/) as referenced by Maxpm.

Comment: @Benjol: if I have to mix smiles and parenthesis, I use `[]` as parenthesis, then I can freely use the smile [this way ;)] ; still bad, mind, but not as itching as doing the other way.

Comment: Hmmm, I never even had a slightest idea of nesting brackets in texts as possibility. So, it is not possible to use different (round, square) brackets to make text with nested brackets more readable? Can any links to examples be given (I have never seen nested brackets in my whole life!)?

Comment: I found some nested brackets in the FontForge FAQ page: http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/faq.html#linespace (paragraph starting `Actually this is not a very useful`)

Comment: When I need a smiley right before a closing parenthesis, I reverse it (like this (: )

Comment: @Noldorin Your comment is supported by Harbrace College Handbook section 17g: "Use brackets . . . when necessary, to replace parentheses within parentheses.

Comment: @htoip: Ah, it's good to know it's not just me then. :-) I'm reading 'parentheses' as 'brackets' and 'brackets' as 'square brackets' btw; to translate into British English...

Comment: @Noldorin Isn't it strange that the nesting in mathematics [()] is the reverse of English ([])?

Comment: @htoip: Yeah slightly odd... but considering the disconnect between the fields, maybe not. I've always thought the `(... [...] ...)` nesting is more logical though!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is acceptable, but you should use it with care. Generally, you should avoid having long texts in parentheses, as the reader will eventually forget that he is inside a parentheses block.

In serious papers and letters, you should avoid it completely, and rather find a way of re-phrase it.

In conversational e-mails, blog posts, StackExchange posts etc. it might be more natural to use it, but the inner parenthesis should never be long (just a couple of words). The most important is to make sure that the reader don't get confused of where the parenthesis start and end.

## Example

#### With nested parentheses

This is a quick example on how to rephrase a potential problematic use of nested
parenthesis.
(It can be a less important section like this (which is quite long, even if it is not important), and when you continue, the reader might be lost in where in the parenthesized text he is, and might wonder if he still is inside any parentheses.)
Anyway, the main text continues here.

#### Re-phrased to remove nesting

This is a quick example on how to rephrase a potential problematic use of nested parenthesis.

(It can be a less important section like this. It is quite long, even if it is not important. Now when you continue, the reader is not lost anymore because the long section is taken out in a separate paragraph, and no inner parentheses can be mistaken for an early termination of the outer section.)

Anyway, the main text continues here.

Comment: Can you give links (or references) with examples of nested brackets? Even better with different types of nested brackets...

Comment: "In conversational e-mails, blog posts, StackExchange posts etc. it might be more appropriate to use it, but the inner parenthesis should never be long (just a couple of words)." Unless you are answering a question on Stack Overflow that is about Lisp.

Comment: I've found that with too many parentheses, it can be hard to make sure each is matched without a text editor or compiler that detects syntax errors (like a programming IDE)

Comment: @T.Webster: Yes, that is exactly why you should _use it with care_ as I said in my answer. A good advice would be to look quickly over what you have written, and see if it is easy to spot the matched parenthese pairs (without the aid of a programming IDE...).

Comment: You are supposed to use square brackets for internal parens, if you must use them.  You are not supposed to nest parens themselves.

Comment: @T.Webster : If you have trouble keeping track of the parenthesis in a text you write, you should consider re-write. If the writer loose track, how should the reader be able to keep track?

Comment: What about optional plurals in serious papers and letters? For example: Some text here (something about the author(s)) more text.

Answer (score 24):

I believe it's *acceptable*, but vaguely considered *poor form*, and I tend to avoid it (often by restructuring a sentence and busting out some emdashes) unless I'm intentionally using it to be cute.

Comment: True. Even single brackets are usually a thing to avoid in full prose, like novels or complicated, abstract texts:  they are most of the time neither pleasant to the eye of the reader nor easy on his mind. Of course there are plenty of situations where they are fine, though.

Comment: @Cerberus 'single brackets' = parentheses?

Comment: @Brad: 'single' = single; 'brackets' = parentheses. :-) "Parentheses" [is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) the American name for what is elsewhere just called "bracket". What Americans call "bracket" is called "square bracket" elsewhere.

Comment: Usually when I notice myself in the need to use two pairs of nested parentheses (or generally when overusing them), I edit the whole sentence so at least my outer parentheses-content is part of the actual text.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: This is one of the *few* places where I feel American English has a better approach.  In computing it is entirely necessary to differentiate with ease and I find myself having to train juniors to say parentheses, brackets, braces, chevrons, guillemets (ok, they never say this "double angle bracket" persists).

Comment: @Orbling: What's wrong with the usual bracket, square bracket, curly bracket, angle bracket etc.? :-) We all learnt the differences in school, and in principle (for non-Americans) the names ought to be easier to remember than using a new word for every character.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Granted, but I am generally pro-jargon.  It makes conversations quicker and reduces confusion.  I find people tend to ask you "what type of bracket", if you just say "bracket", and the others they can mishear.

Comment: @Orbling: Round bracket? Though generally I am of the *parentheses, square bracket, curly brace* camp; *bracket* is just such a nice *square* word, and *brace* so deliciously *curly.*

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Totally agreed, and guillemets are forgotten around about as often as the necessary ALT-codes to enter them.

Comment: +1 Yes. The rules exist only to make a good background that will make breaking of them well seen. You can break rhythm maximally in 1/4 of tacts, or there will be no rhythm.

Comment: I occasionally find myself copying the habit of a former workmate, who referred to angle brackets as madonnas.  So < was "left madonna" or "open madonna", and > was "right madonna" or "close madonna".

Answer (score 13):

Well I do it, but then I spend a lot of time as a mathematician.

If it gets confusing I think using alternative bracket glyphs assists `([{<« »>}])`.

*[Though using the guillemets `(« »)` as brackets can get you in to trouble, as a lot of languages use them as speech marks.<sup>[(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemets#Uses)</sup>]*

Comment: perhaps n00b follow up question, but do the alternative bracket glyphs have the same meaning as parentheses?

Comment: @Brad Cupit: Well, they can be.  But technically they have specific uses, e.g. square brackets are usually used for editorial comments or amendments, annotations, though these uses are not absolute.  Read through this article for a full explanation, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket

Comment: Very good answer. Using different kinds of parenthetical markers can work, though not in editions of manuscripts etc, where each marker has its own function.

Comment: @Cerberus: Aye, only applicable in absence of significant usage.

Comment: As an engineer/programmer I sometimes use different kinds  of brackets for clarity, but only in informal emails and IM conversations.

Comment: Let us all nest parentheses (brackets, whatever), please.  The more we do this, the more it becomes standard English.

Comment: In maths you should not go beyond `([{}])`. Once you need a fourth level you should start repeating yourself. The `<` and `>` symbols have a completely different meaning in maths!

Comment: @David Heffernan: When I said I nest brackets, probably because of my mathematics influence, that was a separate statement to my list of bracket types.  Inequality symbols used as bracketing would certainly be confusing, and would definitely sod up my Mathematica notebooks.

Comment: @Orbling, would not it be more clear to use different types of brackets (round, square, etc.) to make text with nested brakets more readable? Is it permitted?

Comment: @vgv8: I think that was my suggestion, the comments above allude to its acceptability, which rather depends upon the context.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - all of these symbols have completely different meanings in maths.  So if you're writing maths, and you need to nest parentheses; for Heaven's sake, nest parentheses!

Comment: @DavidWallace Not in the maths I typically do. Can you tell me a single universal meaning of these symbols?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Sure. () alter the order of operations. Like ( 2 + 3 ) x 4, whch is 20, but without the parentheses would be 14. () also denotes an open interval - that is, (0,1) is the set of real numbers greater than 0 but less than 1. [] denotes a closed interval, so [0,1] means all the real numbers not less than 0, and not greater than 1. [] is also sometimes used for the floor function, but that's becoming less and less common. {} denotes a set, either with the elements listed or described - for example { 0, 1, 2 } or { all even numbers }. And yes, I do have a degree in mathematics.

Comment: @DavidWallace You are hoist by your own petard. If you wish to reserve [] exclusively for closed intervals then for consistency why not reserve () exclusively for open intervals? Mathematical notation is all about context. When it is clear from the context that [] and {} are being used as parentheses then it is fine to do so. And as for the maths degrees, do you only have the one?  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I think that you and I will have to agree to disagree on this.  If I saw you write an expression in [], I would interpret it to mean the floor function.  If I saw you write an expression in {}, I would interpret it to mean a singleton set.  The context may make abuses of these notations CLEAR, but it would never make them CORRECT.

Comment: @DavidWallace On my desk at the moment, I have a Springer volume titled, *An Introduction to Statistical Modeling of Extreme Values* by Stuart Coles. The page it coincidentally happens to be turned to has an expression `exp{-[1+xi({z-u}/sigma)]^-1/xi}` for the GPD distribution. It may not be the norm in your area of maths but there are plenty of subject areas in maths where it is the norm. I suggest you write to Springer to put them right!!

Comment: Fantastic!  I have just done a survey of the mathematics books on my bookshelf.  I have found plenty of examples of both conventions; and even one book that mixes the two, seemingly at random.  Thank you, @DavidHeffernan for taking the time to make your comments, and opening my eyes to this.  I had obviously never really paid enough attention before, to which types of brackets I was looking at.  I hereby take back my earlier comments.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yeah, but that book is on *statistics*, he said *maths*... ;-)

Answer (score 13):

My English Composition professor told us that if you ever feel you need to use nested parentheses, that is one sure sign you need to rewrite the sentence instead.

Here's what one technical [editor has to say](http://www.johnwoodwark.com/editing/advice/punctuation.html) on the topic:

> Nesting parentheses should be done with square brackets "([ ])". But since square brackets are usually used for citations, this is confusing. The answer is to eliminate all nested parentheses by appropriate rewording. (Dashes, otherwise not recommended, can have a use here.)

Comment: Refactoring is apparently not a concept solely for programming then. ;-)

Comment: @Orbling: Yes, though after I started programming I rankled under the restriction. Why *not* have subgroups set off by extra parens? But the point is, code and mathematical expressions are usually set off with whitespace to be readable, and a good IDE will show you the opening brace when you put the cursor next to the closing brace, etc. Writing is not coding, although sometimes I wish it could be that precise.

Comment: Aye, I certainly sympathise with that view.  Though the great beauty of English is in the myriad of meanings that can be formed from the simplest of constructions.

Comment: The copyeditor on the last edition of one of my books changed the two instances of nested parens into parens on the outside and square brackets on the inside.  It’s formally correct, but not what a programmer would necessarily think to od.

Answer (score 8):

I have found that people who appreciate stressing thoroughly the logical construction of their sentences to make them totally unambiguous tend to use parentheses a lot, and to nest them, even though (see other answers) it's considered poor form. In particular, scientists (especially mathematicians and logicians) seem to do that more commonly than other people.

Comment: I guess you didn't mean that scientists do it more than mathematicians and logicians. :-)

Answer (score 6):

In looking at this question, I was immediately reminded of the work of William Faulkner, an undoubtedly well-known author in the United States.  He is notorious for his complex sentences that can go on for pages.  In some of them, he unapologetically uses nested parentheses.

While Faulkner sets a precedent doing this, it is not at all proof of the 'correct' usage.  His motivation is quite different.  I like the way Louis Rubin puts it in his [essay](http://books.google.com/books?id=gW-Drav6CUoC&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=faulkner%20parentheses&source=bl&ots=ZQKwT0rYxQ&sig=49-YgU5y_tTCZni_y2lJm9pSrXA&hl=en&ei=15HnTbOTM5GFtgfdpvDnCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=faulkner%20parentheses&f=false) *The Dixie Special: William Faulkner and the Southern Literary Renascence*:

> His very style itself, with the long sentences, the liberal deployment of adjectives, the parentheses, and the parentheses within parentheses, proceeds from the conviction that reality can be represented only when presented in its full complexity, leaving out nothing that is important. His admiration for Thomas Wolfe, he said on several occasions, was for that novelist's attempt, however impossible of fulfillment, to put all experience on the head of a pin.

I bring Faulkner's example up for the sake of introducing a different angle on the OP's question.  It may not be the best choice stylistically to nest parentheses, but there have been literary precedents that show the practice.  The example of Faulkner's usage of the nested parentheses shows that there is a purpose in his writing to convey a sense of *complexity* and to *leave nothing out*.

Comment: Judging by that short piece of text, Louis Rubin himself seemed to be showing a fondness of the commas as opposed to parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

Parentheses are a way to stuff more ideas into a sentence than it could otherwise bear.  They make life easier for the writer who is trying to capture all his ideas as they bubble up, but harder for the reader trying to make sense of it all.  If you nest your parentheses, you risk losing your reader entirely.

So I'd say, in your first draft, go ahead and use as many parentheses as you want, but in later drafts you should try to eliminate them — especially the nested ones.

Comment: I would say that separating content with parentheses is an attempt to provide content to the reader in a parallell scope. Using commas, would be a more serialized approach.